# Unable to find what would be the log domain name for gtkbuilder.c

Tags: c, gtk, gtkbuilder

I would like to redirect messages from `g_warning()` and similar functions from [gtkbuilder.c](https://github.com/linuxmint/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkbuilder.c) such as the famous:

> (main.exe:39280): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:34:48.787: Could not find signal
> ha ndler 'on_window_realize'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

using `g_log_set_handler()`. It expects the domain name as the first parameter, which is what I can't seem to find. If `G_LOG_DOMAIN` is not defined in the source then it defaults to `NULL` in which case I won't be able to use `g_log_set_handler()` to redirect it.

What is the log domain name for it or alternatively - how can I redirect those messages after all (I am redirecting them to a GtkTextBuffer)?

Answer (score 1):

GTK is using structured logging, which means the `g_log_set_handler()` won’t work.

`g_log_set_writer_func()` should be used instead to catch every structured log and parse the given `GLogWriterFunc` in the callback.